# How to add total line Dynamic Array formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, dynamic-arrays

I would like to get a total line at the end of my dynamic filter formula in excel.  The problem is how do I shift the total line when the array grows or shrinks?  I always want total at the end of the filtered data.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a stretch, but if you want to do this using excel-formulae then you could try the below:

[image]

Formula in `E5`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",0,FILTER(A5:C14,C5:C14>15000),"","Total",SUMIF(C5:C14,">15000"))&"</s></t>","//s"),SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(C5:C14,">15000")+1,3)),"")
```

I'd advise to keep the 15000 as a reference instead of hardcoded obviously.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! Just a quick question, I tried to replicate the question and used `RANDBETWEEN` to generate the Salaries between 10000 and 20000. I used the same formula, and it worked as expected. When I tried testing the formula by pressing **Shift+F9** to generate a new set of salaries, sometimes I got a **#SPILL!** error in cell `E5`. However, when I replace the data with hardcoded salaries, the formula worked again without error. I am not too sure why this was happening. Would you be able to shed some light on this issue? Much appreciated.

Comment: @TerryW, very odd behaviour since formula evaluation shows all the correct steps. And since there is no data below or next to it, it may seem as though Excel still sees it that way. At this point I don't know what causes this.

Answer (score 1):

Also a bit of a stretch using the idea of indexing from @JvdV:

```
=LET(nrow,COUNTIF(C5:C14,">"&15000),seq,SEQUENCE(nrow+1,3,0),IFS(seq=nrow*3,"",seq=nrow*3+1,"Total",seq=nrow*3+2,SUM(FILTER(C5:C14,C5:C14>15000)),TRUE,INDEX(FILTER(A5:C14,C5:C14>15000),QUOTIENT(seq,3)+1,MOD(seq,3)+1)))
```

[image]

You could if you wished apply bold font using conditional formatting to the output range using the formula

```
=$F5="Total"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little shorter.

```
=LET(f,FILTER(A5:C14,C5:C14>15000),size,ROWS(f),IF(SEQUENCE(size+1)>size,CHOOSE({1,2,3},"","Total",SUM(INDEX(f,,3))),f))
```